# How to fix a window of time in x-axis while creating a timeseries plots of realtime data using bokeh

Tags: python, range, bokeh

I have tried various methods but most of the time the

start=(datetime1(data['DateCreated_DB'].max())-np.timedelta64(1, 'h'))[0].astype(datetime)

end=(datetime1(data['DateCreated_DB'].max())+np.timedelta64(2, 'h'))[0].astype(datetime)

window=Range1d(start,end)
p.x_range=window

this code throws an error some times json serialization problem

if i change the datatype then also some issue.

Please help!